# how to validate mac address in the form field

Tags: regex, validation

I am really new to this. I want to validate mac address in the form field and shows if wrong/invalid format for mac address. I tried to follow xxxmatko coding as in the same question for validate mac address but it shows nothing. only just an input text and does not work really well with the regexp. Happy if someone could help. How to validate mac address in form field ?

```
$(function() {
var regexp = /^(([A-Fa-f0-9]{2}[:]){5}[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}?)+$/i;

$("#mac_address_wifi1").on("input", function(e) {
var tb = $(this);
    var val = tb.val().replace(/[^a-f0-9]/ig, "");
    var r = /([a-f0-9]{2})([a-f0-9]{2})/i;
    while (r.test(val)) {
        val = val.replace(r, '$1' + ':' + '$2');
    }
    val = val.slice(0, 17);
    tb.val(val);    
    tb.toggleClass("badMac", !regexp.test(tb.val()));
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is here:

```
var r = /([a-f0-9]{2})([a-f0-9]{2})/i;
while (r.test(val)) {
    val = val.replace(r, '$1' + ':' + '$2');
}
```

The construct `while (regex)` matches the regex once, then tries again *after* the previous match, as many times as possible.  So you are effectively looping over groups of four hex digits, not two digits like you apparently intended.